# wp-env mysqlcheck error:1130

Tags: javascript, command-line

In Ubuntu 20.04 wp-env is giving me error once i have installed it and while trying to start it with `wp-env start` .The error showing is `mysqlcheck: Got error: 1130: Host '172.29.0.5' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server when trying to connect`.

I have tried....... `CREATE USER 'wp'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpass';` 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'wp'@'%';`

`sudo service mysql restart` .

Changed the `wp-config` with new user and password keeping the DB_HOST same as earlier  ( ie; `localhost`)

Still i am getting the same error . Can somebody please let me know what i have done wrong ?

Comment: You may need to open an issue on the official github repo, this looks like a docker issue not a WordPress issue. I've opened a Q on the meta site asking if WP Env is in the scope of this site https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/is-wp-env-on-topic

Comment: I know it is not a WP specific question , but thought there would be somebody who have faced the same   ............ actually it is a MySQL issue i think  .

Comment: Then this might be better asked on another stack, either way the best place to ask this is on the github repo, you should not be encountering this kind of problem, the maintainers need to know

Comment: Sure so  ......... should i delete this question from here  ? Or wait for a day or two ?

Comment: I don't see why this question should be deleted

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Find the name of your wp-env container

First, you need to locate the name of the container created by wp-env. To do this, in the directory of your project containing .wp-env.json, you must run the following command:

```
docker ps
```

This should give you a list of containers. In the Names column, you’ll see the following information:

```
7b3099bc856ae9db898a196c0465cadb_wordpress_1
7b3099bc856ae9db898a196c0465cadb_tests-wordpress_1
7b3099bc856ae9db898a196c0465cadb_mysql_1
```

In this example, “7b3099bc856ae9db898a196c0465cadb” is the name of the container created by wp-env.

Step 2: Access the directory containing your docker-compose file

Once you have the name of your wp-env container, you can use it to access the directory containing the docker-compose file created by wp-env. To do so, run the following command in your terminal:

```
cd ~/.wp-env/7b3099bc856ae9db898a196c0465cadb
docker-compose down -v
docker-compose up -d
```

This should create a fresh environment.

Step 3: Restart wp-env

Finally, go back to your project folder and run:

```
wp-env start
```

You should then receive a message informing you that your WordPress dev environment is ready.

Source: How to Fix MariaDB Error 1130 with wp-env and Docker https://greys.co/how-to-fix-mariadb-error-1130-wp-env-docker/

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for me the directory was without a dot, so `cd ~/wp-env/9928495e3780fb029b90f57492529982`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error caused "Error establishing a database connection error".

It could be solved by following the instructions above and installing `@wordpress/env` 4.0.0+.